# Getting a script to generate 300 sets of random characters

Tags: php, random, execute

I would like to know how I can get the script below to generate 300 sets of random characters.

This would avoid my having to press the reload button, 300 times.

Here is my script:

```
<?php

function GetID($x){     

$characters = array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9");

shuffle($characters);

for (; strlen($ReqID)<$x;){
$ReqID .= $characters[mt_rand(0, count($characters))];
}

return $ReqID;

}     


$ReqID .= GetID(5);
       $ReqID .= "-";
$ReqID .= GetID(9);
       $ReqID .= "-";
$ReqID .= GetID(5);

echo $ReqID;

$fh = fopen("300_file.txt","a+");

fwrite($fh, ("$ReqID")."\n");

fclose($fh);

?>
```

Plus, if there's a way to simplify the characters as an array, would be a bonus but not required.

Comment: Can you not just call [`uniqid()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) 300x with the more_entropy param? Or does it have to be a shuffle of the given set?

Comment: I don't know how to code it. This is a script I pulled off of PHP.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do the 300 loop, use a for, with your bounds, 0-299 [300]:

```
for($l=0;$l<=299;$l++){
    $out[$l] = array_merge(range('A','Z'),range('a','z'),range(2,9));
}
```

The resulting array, $out, will have 0-299 as the key, and the random characters as the value.

If you want to save this to a file, do:

```
$content = implode("\n", $out);
```

And save the $content string to a file.

Comment: Thank you. I've got the script generating 300 sequences, but now am trying to figure out how to have them each on a seperate line. The 300 numbers can't be in one big chunk/line. The $content=implode("\n", $out); is not working for me, for some reason.

Comment: If you want an HTML line breaks, do: implode("<br />\n", $out); otherwise if you cat the outfile, each entry should be a separate line

Answer (score 1):

simplify your array with

`array_merge(range('A','Z'),range('a','z'),range(2,9))`

use a loop to wash, rinse and repeat 300 times

Comment: Thanks. How would I have it repeat 300 times, that's what I don't know also.

Comment: by looping the relevant bits of your code..you have a loop in your function, so I assume you know how to make a loop..?

Comment: No I don't, this is why I'm asking for help here.

Comment: @Fred: Then you should start with the PHP tutorial.

Comment: The OP actually has I, o, 0 etc missing from the ranges (hence why you have `range(2,9)` so it'd be good if you updated your answer to build the exact original array (`range('A', 'H'), range('J', 'N')...`).